# About the version of blender written in bl_info

Tags: scripting, add-on

When developing an add-on, I write bl_info as follows.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "test_bl_info",
    "author": "taichi",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "3DView",
    "description": "test",
    "warning": "",
    "support": "COMMUNITY",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Object"
}
```

And I distribute add-ons to users.

But will users have to rewrite this bl_info every time a new version of blender comes out?

Is there any way that bl_info is automatically rewritten according to the Blender version that the user is using?

Comment: I would recommend keep at the minimum requirement, only change when required.  eg API change, new feature...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Blender version in the `bl_info` should indicate the version of Blender it was written for. Future releases of Blender may change the API and the version information can be used to perform a simple check whether the add-on may work with the Blender release. Blender 2.8x already displays a warning when an add-on with `blender` lower than `(2, 80, 0)` is installed. Automatically updating the value of `blender` would therefore defeat its purpose.

[image: Warning in preferences]